# Sorting 2d matrix cols and rows in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Given set two - dimensional integers. The array consists of 5 rows and 10 columns.
Each value in the system is a random number between 0 and 20.
Have to write a program that performs the sorting of the array values as follows:
First there arrange the values in each column so that they are sorted in ascending order (top to bottom), then - so there can sort the columns right "comes right" by comparing pairs of values in different columns in the same row (a "comparison lexicography"): comparing two values ​​in two columns in the first row, if they are the same compared to the values in the second row, and so on, and accordingly change the order of columns (see example in the third printing of the array, below).
To display the array before sorting and after each of the two phases of the emergency.
for example :
[image: example and output of my code]
I stuck with the sorting of the each cols. I don't get the sorting i want. I would like to get your help please.
This is my code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "malloc.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

#define N 5
#define M 10
#define LOW 0
#define HIGH 20

void initRandomArray(int arr[N][M]);
void printArray(int arr[N][M]);
void SortInColumn(int arr[N][M],int m);
int main()
{
    int arr[N][M];
    int m;
    m=M;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); //To clear the stack of Random Number
    initRandomArray(arr);
    printf("Before sorting:\n");
    printArray(arr);
    printf("Sorting elements in each column:\n");
    SortInColumn(arr,M);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void initRandomArray(int arr[N][M])
{

    int i,j;
    for (i=0 ; i<N ; i++)
        for (j=0 ; j<M ; j++)
        {
         arr[i][j]=LOW+rand()%(HIGH-LOW+1);
        }

}
void printArray(int arr[N][M])
{ 
    int i,j;
    for (i=0 ; i<N ; i++)
    {
        for (j=0 ; j<M ; j++)
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
         printf("\n");
    }
}
void SortInColumn(int arr[][M],int m)
{
    int i,j;
    int temp;
    for( i=m-1 ; i>=0 ; i--)
        {   
        for(j=0; j<N-1; j++)
            if (arr[i][j]>arr[i][j+1]) // compare adjacent item
                 {
                  temp=arr[i][j];
                  arr[i][j]=arr[i][j+1];
                  arr[i][j+1]=temp;
                 }
        }
        for (i=0 ; i<N ; i++)
        {
            for (j=0 ; j<M ; j++)
                printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
             printf("\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: are you allowed to use `qsort(3)`?

Comment: no,i can use bubble sort max sort or merge sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mine, and it runs and gives the correct answer.

Basically, you did two things wrong.

- you need three loops instead of two. The outer loop loops around each columns. the second loop makes sure you compare each column N-1 times since for each run you get one item in the right place. The inner loop do the adjacent comparison.
- you need to change the comparison between `arr[i][k]` and `arr[i][k+1]` to `arr[i][k]` to `arr[i+1][k]`. Because you want to compare them in the same column, you hold the value `k` (column) unchanged and change the rows `i`.

  ```
  void SortInColumn(int arr[][M],int m)
  {
      int i,j,k;
      int temp;

      for( k=0 ; k<m ; ++k)
      {
          for(j=0; j<N-1; j++)
          {
                  for(i=0; i < N-1 - j; i++)
                  {
                          if (arr[i][k]>arr[i+1][k]) // compare adjacent item
                          {
                                  temp=arr[i][k];
                                  arr[i][k]=arr[i+1][k];
                                  arr[i+1][k]=temp;
                          }
                  }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

BTW, this algorithm is very bad in performance in general. You may want to try something else.

Comment: Thanks guy! stupid me! Yes you right it's kinda shit algorithm but i don't really mind.we don't gets point for choosing better or worse alog.

Comment: Hey John Smith! i am stuck in the second part of the sorting!, I don't know how to define the cols 1 and cols 2 for swapping between them! i would like to get your help.This is my code

Comment: void SortColumns(int arr[][M])
{   int row,cols,i=0;
 int col1=arr[M-1-i];
 int col2=arr[row][cols+1];
 compareColumns(arr,col1,col2);

}
int compareColumns(int arr[][M], int col1, int col2)
{
 int row,cols;
 for ( row=0 ; row < N ; row ++ );
  {
   for( cols=0 ; cols < M-1 ; cols++)
   {
    if(arr[row][cols]>arr[row][cols+1])
    {
     col1=arr[row][cols];
     col2=arr[row][cols+1];
     swapColumns(arr,col1,col2);
    }
   }
  }
 printArray(arr);
}
void swapColumns(int arr[][M], int col1, int col2)
{
 int temp;
 temp=col1;
 col1=col2;
 col2=temp;

}

Answer (score -1):

Let's look at your `SortInColum` function. I've changed the formatting to get a better understanding of what's going on, and renamed some variables.

```
void SortInColumn(int arr[][M],int m)
{
  int row,col;
  int temp;
  for( row=m-1 ; row>=0 ; row--) // foreach row
  {
    for(col=0; col<N-1; col++) { // foreach column
      if (arr[row][col]>arr[row][col+1]) { // comparing adjacent entries 
                                           //  in different cols? Why? 
        temp=arr[row][col];
        arr[row][col]=arr[row][col+1];
        arr[row][j+1]=temp;
      }
  }
  printArray(arr);

}
```

This function (given some changes) will sorts a single column, you can then call this for each column. Hopefully this gives you a good starting point.

Comment: I tried but i don't success to do it. while i define a 2d array by 5 rows and 10 cols arr[N][M], I got a problem of definition the array

Comment: I was attempting to give you hints as to what needed to be changed. First, you are comparing items across different columns. Maybe you want to change that to compare across different rows? And second, the function give some changes will sort a single column. You'll need to either modify it to sort a given column and call it for every col or add another loop. You don't need go create a second array.

Comment: Thanks for the hint and for the helping!